# python-apscheduler: dependent python-concurrent.futures not installed

Tags: apt, python

I install `python-apscheduler`, but dependent `python-concurrent.futures` not installed.

Is this package bug?

Environment:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.17
```

#### Procedure

Install python-apscheduler

```
$ sudo apt install python-apscheduler
```

Prepare the following script

```py
$ cat a.py
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from apscheduler.executors.pool import ThreadPoolExecutor

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print "hello"
```

If I execute it, an error will occur.

```
$ python a.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 1, in <module>
    from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apscheduler/schedulers/blocking.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apscheduler.schedulers.base import BaseScheduler, STATE_STOPPED
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apscheduler/schedulers/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    from apscheduler.executors.pool import ThreadPoolExecutor
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apscheduler/executors/pool.py", line 2, in <module>
    import concurrent.futures
ImportError: No module named concurrent.futures
```

`python-concurrent.futures` is not installed:

```
$ apt list --installed python-apscheduler python-concurrent.futures
Listing... Done
python-apscheduler/bionic,bionic,now 3.4.0-2ubuntu1 all [installed]
```

`apt depends` doesn't show `python-concurrent.futures`:

```
$ apt depends python-apscheduler
python-apscheduler
  Depends: python-pkg-resources
  Depends: python-six (>= 1.4.0)
  Depends: python-tz
  Depends: python-tzlocal
  Depends: <python:any> (<< 2.8)
    python:i386
    python
  Depends: <python:any> (>= 2.7.5-5~)
    python:i386
    python
```

`Build-Depends: python-concurrent.futures` is written in `debian/control`. I get apscheduler_3.4.0-2ubuntu1.debian.tar.xz  from [the package index](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python-apscheduler0).

See `debian/control`:

```
Source: apscheduler
Section: python
Priority: optional
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
XSBC-Original-Maintainer: Laszlo Boszormenyi (GCS) <gcs@debian.org>
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 11), dh-python,
 python-all (>= 2.7),
 python-setuptools, python-setuptools-scm,
 python-concurrent.futures, python-tzlocal, python-six, python-pytest,
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: thanks. but didn't work. The universe repository is already active. `$ sudo add-apt-repository universe` said `'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.` I found `deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe` in /etc/apt/sources.list. (I'm japanese)

Answer (score 1):

This is a packaging bug. The PyPi version of `apcheduler` does depend on `futures`, so `python-concurrent.futures` should have been a `Depends` of `python-apscheduler`. I suspect the reason this has gone unnoticed is that there are only two other packages that depend on `python-apscheduler`:

```
# apt-cache rdepends python-apscheduler
python-apscheduler
Reverse Depends:
  python-watcher
  archipel-agent-action-scheduler
```

Of which, `python-watcher` indirectly depends on `python-concurrent.futures` via other packages. And `archipel-agent-action-scheduler` died sometime in [May 2018](http://web.archive.org/web/20180801000000*/http://archipelproject.org/), so I doubt there are many users of it.